# SharePoint 2013 Asset Library

Tags: document-library, library

I have a SharePoint 2013 asset library - by default it displays images - how can I change this behavior - I have already created a filter by clause and this does not work as expected for me (I would like to do this OOB if possible)

Comment: Can you give some more information how you want to change the behavior?

Comment: For example, when an end-user goes to the Google web site they get only a search box in SharePoint I added two web parts - one for the search box and another web part for the search results - by default the search results shows me all of the items in the asset library (I have attempted to change the query multiple times with no such luck). For example {?{searchTerms} (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)}

Answer (score 0):

The default asset library view is "Thumbnails," which displays square thumbnails for images and videos. The "All Assets" view is a list view that displays thumbnails in a "Thumbnail Preview" column. You can create a new view based on All Assets and modify it to not display the Thumbnail Preview column. Then you can set that as the default view for the library.